# \exists quantifier and being explicit about quantity

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have a question regarding the use of the $ \exists $ quantifier when trying to signify explicit quantities.

Consider

$F:$ the set of all fruits

$A(x):$ x is an apple

$R(x):$ x is rotten

If I wanted to express 'One apple is rotten' would this be logically sound?

$\exists x \in F, \forall y \in F,  x \neq y \wedge R(x) \wedge \neg R(y)$

Also how would the above be different from:

$\exists x \in F, \forall y \in F,  x \neq y \Rightarrow R(x) \wedge \neg R(y)$

Thanks!

Comment: I thought this was supposed to be about rotten apples, not rotten fruit.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Oops! Derp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Asaf pointed out, there are a couple of flaws with how you've formulated your expressions. The following should help:

"At least one apple is rotten." translates to "There is a fruit (call it $x$) that is both an apple and rotten.":
$$
\exists x \in F~~~[A(x) \land R(x)]
$$

"Exactly one apple is rotten." translates to "There is a particular type of fruit (call it $x$) such that for any other fruit (call it $y$), the other fruit can only be an apple and be rotten if and only if the other fruit was actually the particular type of fruit.":
$$
\exists x \in F~~~\forall y \in F,~~[A(y) \land R(y) \iff x=y]
$$

Comment: Don't the $A(y)$ & $R(y)$ need to be negated though? Also doesn't $x=y$ need to be $x \neq y$ ?

Comment: @tuba09 Sorry I had a typo; it's fixed now. Also, this link might explain how I expressed uniqueness in terms of quantifiers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification

Comment: Oww! I'm trying real hard to wrap my head around this! Might take me a while, but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

In the first form, you say that *every* member of $F$ is not $x$, and thus you allow $x$ itself. So essentially you are stating that amongst other things, $x\neq x$. This is impossible, of course.

On the other hand, in the second form you say that *if* $x\neq y$, then $y$ is not rotten. This means that it is possible that $x$ itself is rotten.

Comment: $\exists x \in F, A(x) \wedge R(x)$ Would this be logically sound then? I understand that it states that there is some apple that is rotten, but this statement alone does not preclude the domain from consisting entirely of rotten apples. I want to specify the exact number of apples.

Comment: Don't try and shoot all around and hope to blurt the right formulation. Think about it, think about what I wrote, and what Adriano wrote. Then think about the definitions of the quantifiers and the logical connectives. Then try to state "There exists exactly one rotten apple" in a language which is as close to formal logic as possible (i.e. use words which translate directly to symbolic form, not phrases like "exactly one"). Then write the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach that can be easily generalized to assert the existence of exactly $n$ objects with a given property $P$.  (For example, $P(x)$ could be defined as $A(x) \wedge R(x)$, meaning that $x$ is a rotten apple.)

Define the sentence $\psi_n$ saying 
$$\exists x_1 \cdots \exists x_n\, \left(\bigwedge_{1 \le i < j \le n} x_i \ne x_j \wedge \bigwedge_{1 \le i \le n} P(x_i)\right).$$
This says that there are $n$ objects, all different (no two are the same) and all with property $P$.  So it says that *at least* $n$ objects have property $P$.  Then the sentence $\psi_n \wedge \neg \psi_{n+1}$ says that *exactly* $n$ objects have property $P$.

For example, the sentence
$$\left(\exists x_1\,P(x_1)\right) \wedge \neg\left(\exists x_1\exists x_2\, \left(x_1 \ne x_2 \wedge P(x_1) \wedge P(x_2)\right)\right)$$
says that exactly one object has property $P$.